# Optimization, program is lagging

Tags: performance

[image]

What did o do wrong? I can't work Blender is lagging.

I turned off shadows, lines and etc. but it's still lagging. How i can optimize my work process?

Tree, house, wood and rocks i made in sculpting. I make remesh 0.01 on each item. Leafs were joined.

Answer (score 4):

Simply *hiding* objects still keeps them in memory.
You need to *disable* them.

Don't use the eye icon. Use the **screen icon**.

<sup>Memory goes from 300MiB to just 30 when object is disabled</sup>
[image]

Comment: Good catch, if you switch it off/on enough times you'll get negative memory load :D

Comment: (it was a joke, hope i didn't cause any headaches :))